# Use class to deserialize XML, but ignore any members that are not specified in class

Tags: c#, xml, class, serialization

I have a rather complex XML file I want to deserialize into a class object.
I´ve used an online tool to create a C# class from the XML to deserialize to.

```
XmlSerializer serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(quotes.DOCUMENTS))

using (Stream reader = new FileStream(quoteFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    i = (DOCUMENTS)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

However, from time to time new members are added to the XML - I do not need to care about them, but the code throws an exception when stumbling about them.

How can I configure the class or adapt the code to simply ignore things in the XML that are not included in the class?

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class DOCUMENTS
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: you can use `XmlIgnore`, however you need to put that on every element you want to ignore. There's no automatic way of serializing/de-serializing only a specific subset of members from a type.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain the issue is, there might be something new in the xml, so it isn´t part of my class. but I want to simply ignore additional stuff in the XML that is not part of my class (so I can´t add the XmlIgnore Attribute to anything)

Comment: I suppose your class needs to implement `IXmlSerializable` for that

Comment: What exception is it throwing? It should automatically ignore extra unknown XML elements.

Comment: New object are ignored.  If you are getting exceptions it is probably the namespaces that is giving the issues.

Comment: I´ve read that new objects should be ignored, but it just isn´t the case and I have no clue what could be the reason .

The inner exception is "Input string was not in a correct format" - if I adapt the C# class to add missing stuff, it works again

Comment: Sounds like there's some integer/date parsing going on which you're not telling us. A [mcve] of the class definition and a failing XML would help immensely.